# How to get the python Counter output ordered by order of inputs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, output, counter

I have been working on getting the count(frequency) and then making the graph representation of it.

I am using `Counter` class from `collections` using python. I want the output of the `Counter` in the order of the first come object.

for example:

```
offset=['a','b','c','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c']
counts = Counter(offset)
print counts
```

output is:

```
Counter({'c': 6, 'b': 4, 'a': 2})
```

As I want the output to be as follows, in the order of the first come object:

```
Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6})
```

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Related question [Counter.most_common(n) how to override arbitrary ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076195/counter-most-commonn-how-to-override-arbitrary-ordering/)

Comment: Note that starting from Python 3.7, Counter is guaranteed to preserve insertion order.

Answer (score 10):

## OrderedCounter by (2 lines long) multiple inheritance

Following wonderful speech [Super considered super](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) by
Raymond Hettinger we can use multiple inheritance:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, Counter

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass
```

and use it:

```
>>> counter = OrderedCounter("abracadabra")
>>> for key, value in counter.items():
...    print key, value
a 5
b 2
r 2
c 1
d 1
```

This is all you need for your task.

### Fixing a slightly confusing representation

Let us do a bit more tests and see, what "result" we get:

```
>>> counter = OrderedCounter("cbaaa")
>>> counter
OrderedCounter({'a': 3, 'c': 1, 'b': 1})
```

Oh - this looks wrong, expected order is "c", "b", "a". Let us test it printing the keys and values:

```
>>> for key, value in counter.items():
...    print key, value
c 1
b 1
a 3
```

This looks correct (and it is exactly what really counts for using in your code).

It turns out, that the class we have created is just producing a bit confusing representation.

This can be fixed:

```
class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%r)" % (self.__class__.__name__, OrderedDict(self))
```

and when used:

```
>>> counter = OrderedCounter("cbaaa")
>>> counter
OrderedCounter({'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'a': 1})
```

## Full version from the Raymond Hettinger speech (added pickling)

Full version provided in the speech is adding one more method `__reduce__` which allows pickling
the object properly.

```
from collections import OrderedDict, Counter

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    """Counter that remembers the order elements are first seen"""
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%r)" % (self.__class__.__name__, OrderedDict(self))

    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (OrderedDict(self),)
```

Anyway, in most cases you will manage with the simplest version of the `OrderedCounter` class.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

sorry, I misunderstood. try this.
I implemented that using queue concept.

```
q = []
ret = []
for i in offset:
  if q.count(i)==0: q.insert(i, 0)
while len(q):
  item = q.pop()
  ret.append((item, d.get(item)))
print(ret)
```

Comment: How does that guarantee the output is in the order the objects were first counted?

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood about ordering. Please check it again

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries in python are just hash tables so they don't have any sort of order. You can never print out a sorted list. But you can convert them to a list of tuples and sort that.

```
from collections import Counter
import operator
offset=['a','b','c','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c']
counts = Counter(offset)
print(sorted(counts.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0)))
#[('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('c', 6)]
```

Comment: Sorting the output of counter does not guarantee that the elements will be in the order of the first come object.

Comment: I'm just printing it to show how it works. Obviously he can store it as a variable if that's what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do it "the old fashion way" using an ordered dictionary that guarantees to retain the order in which elements are first inserted:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

offset = ['a','b','c','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c']
counts = OrderedDict()
for elt in offset:
    try:
        counts[elt] += 1
    except KeyError:
        counts[elt] = 1

print(counts)
```

**Result:**

```
OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('c', 6)])
```

Comment: it is not an "old fashioned" way. How else would you do it better without an ordered dict?

Comment: Plus one, as it is the only answer that honors the order in which the elements are first counted.

Comment: hehe, thank you - what I meant by "old fashion way" was that it was to be done without the use of a higher order function like counter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use such a methodology:

```
from collections import Counter
offset=['a','b','c','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c']
counts = Counter(offset)

for letter in offset:
    if letter in counts:
        print (letter + ": " + str(counts[letter]))
        counts.pop(letter)
```

That works as below:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
a: 2
b: 4
c: 6
```

You can store the pairs in a list instead of printing.